# I have a list of enemies but i cannot figure out how to keep them on screen. (Space invaders)

Tags: python, pygame

enemy.x     did not work because after the chosen enemy was killed is disappears from the list. I tried other ways and managed to get them to stop however they would not come back. This is my first game so i am not familiar with these possible errors. Please help :)

```
def level1():
        shipX = 462
        shipY = 668
        bg = pygame.image.load('spacebackground.png')
        ship1 = pygame.image.load('ship1.png')
        lives = pygame.image.load('ship1.png')
        lasers = []


        enemy_x = 50
        enemy_x2 = 50
        enemy_x3 = 50
        enemy1 = pygame.image.load('enemy1.png')
        enemy1 = pygame.transform.scale(enemy1, (50, 50))
        enemies = []

        for i in range(10):
            enemies.append(pygame.Rect(enemy_x, 100, 50, 50))
            enemy_x += 65
        for i in range(10):
            enemies.append(pygame.Rect(enemy_x2, 150, 50, 50))
            enemy_x2 += 65
        for i in range(10):
            enemies.append(pygame.Rect(enemy_x3, 200, 50, 50))
            enemy_x3 += 65

        #Event handling
        while True:
            clock.tick(60)

            laserX = shipX + 23
            laserY = 658
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
                if (pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_SPACE]) != 0:
                    lasers.append(pygame.Rect(laserX, laserY, 5, 20))

            #setting background

            bg = pygame.transform.scale(bg, (1024, 768))
            shipRect = pygame.Rect(shipX, shipY, 50, 50)
            ship1 = pygame.transform.scale(ship1, (50, 50))
            lives = pygame.transform.scale(lives, (25, 25))

            if (pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_RIGHT]) != 0:
                shipX += 20
            if (pygame.key.get_pressed()[pygame.K_LEFT]) != 0:
                shipX += -20
            for enemy in enemies:
                for laser in lasers:
                    if laser.colliderect(enemy):
                        enemies.remove(enemy)
                        lasers.remove(laser)
                        break

            for laser in lasers:
                laser.move_ip(0, -10)
            for laser in lasers:
                if laser.y <= -20:
                    lasers.remove(laser)

            if shipX <= 0:
                shipX = 0
            if shipX >= 974:
                shipX = 974

            screen.blit(bg, (0,0))
            for laser in lasers:
                pygame.draw.rect(screen, (red), laser)
            for enemy in enemies:
                screen.blit(enemy1, enemy.topleft)
                enemy.x += 1

            screen.blit(ship1, (shipRect))
            screen.blit(lives, (5,733))`enter code here`
            screen.blit(lives, (33,733))

            #update Display
            pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: What, _exactly_, is the problem?  Do you just want to keep dead enemies in the list?  Do you want enemies to _never_ vanish (leaving a wreck or something), or vanish only later (after an explosion animation)?  What does "tried other ways" mean --- what other ways?  What does "managed to get them to stop" mean --- stop what?  What are you trying to do, what's happening instead, and why is that wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your enemies are disappearing because you remove them from the list `enemies`:

```
for enemy in enemies:
  for laser in lasers:
    if laser.colliderect(enemy):
      enemies.remove(enemy)    # <---- here
      lasers.remove(laser)
      break
```

Once the enemy is removed from the list, it will no longer be drawn.

What you want to do is keep track of which enemies are 'alive' and which are 'dead'.  You can do this either be creating a class for enemies which contains a boolean `alive`, or by maintaining a parallel array of boolean values.

For example:

```
# Set up `enemies` list
alive = [True for e in enemies]
for enemy in enemies:
  for laser in lasers:
    if laser.colliderect(enemy):
      alive[enemies.index(enemy)] = False
      lasers.remove(laser)
      break
```

Then, when you are rendering enemies, simply check to make sure the enemy is alive before drawing it.  Then, when you want the enemy to reappear, simple set the value back to `true` and it will be drawn again.  Note that the enemy will still be where it was, so you will want to either move it off screen, or also make sure you don't detect laser collisions on dead enemies.

GLHF